# TSQL: Table design for team structure that changes each month

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble coming up with a design to cope with a 4-level team structure that can change each month.

**Level1: the lowest level**

```
YearMonth int
PanelID   varchar(8)
PanelName varchar(50)
StaffID   varchar(8)
```

- YearMonth stored in YYYYMM format
- panelname must be unique each month
- panelID must be unique each month
- An employee (StaffID) can only manage one panelID per yearmonth
  -

**Level2: Manager of Level1**

```
 YearMonth:  int
 Level2Name: varchar(50)
 L2ManagerID:  varchar(8)
```

- a manager (L2ManagerID) can only manage one Level2 per YearMonth
- Level2Name is unique per YearMonth

**Level3: Manager of Level2**

```
 YearMonth: int
 Level3Name: varchar(50)
 L3ManagerID:  varchar(8)
```

- a manager (L3ManagerID) can only manage one Level3 per YearMonth
- Level3Name is unique per YearMonth

**Level4: Manager of Level3**

```
 YearMonth: int
 Level4Name: varchar(50)
 L4ManagerID:  varchar(8)
```

- a manager (L4ManagerID) can only manage one Level4 per YearMonth
- Level4Name is unique per yearmonth

**Relationships**

- Level4 has a one-to-many relationship with Level3
- Level3 has a one-to-many relationship with Level2
- Level2 has a one-to-many relationship with Level1

Can anyone advise what the best structure would be to manage this? How could this be updated each month?

I've had a look at unique constraints which I think would solve some design problems but I'm not sure where best to use them or what primary keys should be used.

I'd appreciate any guidance.

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2, soon to upgrade to 2014.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the structure of the [AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) database. This caters for multi-level management hierarchies. Obviously you'll need to tailor it to your requirements but will make a good starting block.

Comment: The adventureworks database only seems to show what the structure is 'now' and doesn't seem to be able to cope with history in the way I described?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use INT type for your ID fields.
2. Learn what is an "IDENTITY"
3. Learn what is a PRIMARY KEY
4. Learn what is a FOREIGN KEY
5. Learn what "UPDATE" statement is
   After you understand the concepts, you might answer your question or ask better one.